# VBA change checkbox fill color when checked

Tags: forms, excel, checkbox, vba

I have a multi-worksheet workbook that has many form control (not ActiveX) checkboxes throughout it. I'm looking for some VBA that will change the background (fill) color of ALL the checkboxes when it is checked (True). I've seen code for a single checkbox, but not multiple/all boxes. I know just enough VBA to be dangerous, but I'm up to learning anythimg new.

Comment: `I've seen code for a single checkbox` Simply place that code in a sub use that in the click event of your checkbox. You will have to use `Application.Caller` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comments, see this example.

`CheckBox3` is in `Sheet1` and `CheckBox2` is in `Sheet2`

```
Sub CheckBox3_Click()
    Dim actvWs As Worksheet
    Dim CB As String

    Set actvWs = ActiveSheet
    CB = Application.Caller

    ColorCB actvWs, CB

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub

Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    Dim actvWs As Worksheet
    Dim CB As String

    Set actvWs = ActiveSheet
    CB = Application.Caller

    ColorCB actvWs, CB

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub

Sub ColorCB(ws As Worksheet, Cbox As String)
    With ws.Shapes(Cbox)
        '~~> 13 is for Yellow, 1 is for White
        .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = IIf(.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn, 13, 1)
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    End With
End Sub
```

If all the `_Click()` of all Checkboxes are in the same module then you can move these two lines at the top of the module so that you don't have to declare them in every `Sub`.

```
Dim actvWs As Worksheet
Dim CB As String
```

Comment: Nice answer. if there would be a lot of checkboxes though, it might make sense to create a custom class that takes one checkbox `With Events` - and provides the code for the `_Click` event here. Then you'd only have to assign all checkboxes to those "wrappers" - and have only one `_Click` event...

Comment: @PeterAlbert: Absolutely :)